# Can the use of word "when" be interpreted as provided to the context that..."?

Tags: word-usage

Can the use of word "when" be interpreted as provided to the context that..."?

**Example 1**

> Why do I have teeth when I don't use my food?

**Example 2**

> Why are you talking to me so loudly right now when I'm your best friend and always talk to you gently.

**Example 3**

> Why are you acting like you don't want to help me when I helped you last time.

Comment: Oxford Languages gives as its third definition : _in view of the fact that; considering that.
"why bother to paint it when you can photograph it with the same effect?"_

Comment: You can use 'when' is such cases instead of **since**.

Comment: Or "though" or "even though"

Comment: This is a basic definition of 'when' so this could easily be answered with a dictionary. Voting to close.

Comment: I don't know what "provided to the context that" means. I don't think that it's a common way of expressing any idea in English.